# R pathview color scale change

Tags: r

I'm working with the R pathview package to map log2FC values on a KEGG pathway. The thing is that the code automatically gives a color range with red being upregulated and green being downregulated. I would very much like to change the two but have not yet found how to do it. Anyone any ideas? currently i'm using this code:

```
pv.out <- pathview(gene.data = lala[,1:4], pathway.id = "00480", species = "hsa", kegg.native = TRUE, match.data=FALSE, multi.state = TRUE, out.suffix = "yolo", same.layer = FALSE, keys.align="y",  limit = 0.585, bins = 15)
```

but for the node.cols function it somehow does not work for me idk why...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `low` and `high` arguments to the `pathview` function to control the colors that it uses to autogenerate the plots in your working directory. This code will switch the upregulated values to gold and the downregulated values to blue:

```
library(pathview)
data(gse16873.d)
pv.out <-
  pathview(
    gene.data = gse16873.d[, 1],
    pathway.id = "00480",
    species = "hsa",
    kegg.native = TRUE,
    match.data = FALSE,
    multi.state = TRUE,
    out.suffix = "yolo",
    same.layer = FALSE,
    keys.align = "y",
    limit = 0.585,
    bins = 15,
    low=list(gene="steelblue"),
    high=list(gene="gold")
  )
```

Per the documentation (`?pathview`):

`low`, `mid`, `high`:
each is a list of two colors with "gene" and "cpd" as the names. This argument specifies the color spectra to code gene.data and cpd.data. When data are 1 directional (TRUE value in both.dirs), only mid and high are used to specify the color spectra. Default spectra (low-mid-high) "green"-"gray"-"red" and "blue"-"gray"-"yellow" are used for gene.data and cpd.data respectively. The values for 'low, mid, high' can be given as color names ('red'), plot color index (2=red), and HTML-style RGB, ("#FF0000"=red).